# Why does JSON Schema maximum not work in allOf?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Given the following JSON schema:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "properties": {
    "pageA": {
      "properties": {
        "a": { "type": "number" },
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "a": { "maximum": 10 }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "b": { "type": "number" },
              "c": { "type": "string" }
            }
          },
          "else": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "if": {
                  "properties": {
                    "a": { "maximum": 20 }
                  }
                },
                "then": {
                  "properties": {
                    "e": { "type": "number" },
                    "f": { "type": "string" }
                  }
                },
                "else": {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "if": {
                        "properties": {
                          "a": { "maxiumum": 30 }
                        }
                      },
                      "then": {
                        "properties": {
                          "i": { "type": "number" },
                          "j": { "type": "string" }
                        }
                      },
                      "else": {
                        "properties": {
                          "k": { "type": "number" },
                          "l": { "type": "string" }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect:

```json
{
    "pageA": {
      "a": 31,
      "k": "50"
    }
}
```

To generate "Invalid type. Expected Number but got String." but it is valid. I understand any properties nested within an `allOf` cannot be caught by `additionalProperties`, and it appears that the validation is also applying in the similar way.

Comment: Your suggestion about nested `properties` is not correct and unrelated to `allOf` applicator. `additionalProperties` works based on values found in properties of the same schema object, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your schema. The first is super simple to solve. A typo (We've all done it).

`"a": { "maxiumum": 30 }` Should read `maximum`.

Now let's take a look at the specification to see what `maximum` does...

> The value of "maximum" MUST be a number, representing an inclusive
> upper limit for a numeric instance.
>
> If the instance is a number, then this keyword validates only if the
> instance is less than **or exactly equal** to "maximum".

https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.2.2

Given 30 is exactly equal to 30, you triggered your `then` clause as opposed to your `else` clause.

If you want the value to be EXCLUSIVE, there's another keyword... `exclusiveMaximum`, which does just that.

You can see that in action here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/8Yi6e

Comment: Yes. My work colleague just pointed out the spelling mistake. And it should have been 31, I updated the value. Thanks!